Reset beamer original block colors when using a structure theme
Is there a way to rest the color for definitions, examples, theorems and other blocks to their default – blue, green, etc. – when using a theme with a structure color presentation-wise? Below the code I'm using:
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme[named=IndianRed]{structure}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsubsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{definition}
\centering some definition
\end{definition}

\end{frame}
\end{document}

Thanks in advance.

The orchid colour theme (used by the Madrid theme) uses a muted version of structure colour for the block titles (bg=structure.fg!75!black). You can redefine the block titles to use the original blendedblue instead of the structure colour:
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=beamer@blendedblue!75!black}
\makeatother
\usecolortheme[named=IndianRed]{structure}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsubsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{definition}
\centering some definition
\end{definition}

\end{frame}
\end{document}


Although with your shade of red, I'd go for a bit duskier blue:
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}


\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=beamer@blendedblue!55!gray!75!black}
\makeatother

\usecolortheme[named=IndianRed]{structure}
\colorlet{red}{IndianRed}
\colorlet{green}{green!40!lightgray}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \hbox to .5\paperwidth{\hfil\insertsubsectionhead\hfil}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{definition}
\centering some definition
\end{definition}

\begin{example}
content...
\end{example}

\begin{alertblock}{title}
content...
\end{alertblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}



great! I assume there is a blendedgreen or similar for example blocks, a blendedred for alert blocks so on and so forth? Thanks again!

@Matteo No, for the other colours beamer simply uses red, green etc. And these other blocks don't change with the structure colour theme, so aren't relevant for this question.
